# Will loopback address work in android phones?

Tags: android, network-programming

I want to know if the same loop back address(127.0.0.1) that we use in a computer work in android phones also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On all the devices I've used, yes. I use it for xmms2 IPC. You will however need to have the `INTERNET` permission.

Comment: Just to be clear for those new to Android development: @Zharf is talking about this [INTERNET](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#INTERNET) permission, added to the body of your AndroidManifest.xml file, like this: `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`

Answer (score 0):

Only if your phone is running a web server - A few people have done so:
[Running AMP (apache mysql php) on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6571911/running-amp-apache-mysql-php-on-android)

Comment: Why do you think so? I just tested it on my phone using Terminal Emulator. I pinged 127.0.0.1 and it worked without a problem. I'm not running any servers or anything. This was on Gingerbread.

Comment: My initial assumption was that the OP wanted to view web pages - I now realize that there isn't really anything in his question to suggest this