# PHP coding in Android

Tags: php, android

I want to ask if I can run virtual server, MySQL, and a PHP editor on Android (4.1 for example)? I know my question is simple, but I didn't find anything helpful in my searches.

Comment: Possily duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6571911/running-amp-apache-mysql-php-on-android. Linux installer will solve your problems I think. https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.galoula.LinuxInstall

Answer (score 1):

I use an app called [Servers Ultimate](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.icecoldapps.serversultimate), it makes life quite simple

Answer (score 0):

Look into Bit Web Server (PHP,MySQL,PMA). It's a web server with PHP, MySQL as well as PHPMyAdmin - built on Android. It cost $2 and it's available on Google Play: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.andi.serverweb&feature=related_apps#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEwOSwiY29tLmFuZGkuc2VydmVyd2ViIl0.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Or you can take alook at this 
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.fun2code.android.pawserver&feature=nav_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDMsImRlLmZ1bjJjb2RlLmFuZHJvaWQucGF3c2VydmVyIl0.

Paw Server is able to run php , i guess by transferring the code to another server and rendering the reponse..

Answer (score 0):

Have a look on my app - [Android Web Developer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.kidinov.awd) (IDE/Code Editor for web developers). It contains a lot features e.g.

- Support all major web languages and formats: PHP, JavaScript, CSS, HTML
- A lot of ways to reach your project ( FTP, FTPS, SFTP, WEBDav and growing)
- Code highlighting
- Code completion
- Error checking
- Hardware keyboard support (e.g hotkeys)
- Code beautifying with one click
- Tablet ready UI
- Line numbering
- Quick preview of your page
- Highlighting the current line
- Search and replace with regular expressions
- Unlimited Undo/redo
- Full screen mode
- Recent projects
- Periodical autosaving
- Rename/create/delete/copy-paste files inside you project

Hope this helps.

[image]