# Running my website (html5, js, php) on Android device (locally / offline)

Tags: php, android

I would like to run my website (which is not public and not have to be), which includes one `index.html`, few `JS` and `PHP` files on my `Android device` locally / offline.

`HTML` and `JS` is working fine. But unfortuntately the PHP execution doesn't work on my mobile device.

Is there any way to solve this issue, to make my few `PHP` files run locally on my mobile device?

Comment: The accepted answer on this thread might be relevant : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6571911/running-amp-apache-mysql-php-on-android

Comment: Potentially need to install a Web Server that can process PHP Scripts. There is not a way to do this natively. The link that was just posted also addresses this pretty well.